# Java - Determine difference between user entering \n and pressing enter in html form

Tags: java, html, json, spring, postgresql

Searched the web for this but not sure I'm asking the question correctly. I have a web form with a textarea. Users can type what ever they want (can paste emails, etc). When they submit, I escape things like newline so that when I store in a PostgreSQL db (json column type) it saves correctly. That all works fine. However, if a user type something like `c:\foo\bar\notworking.txt` the `\n` is treated like a new line so I end up with

```
c:\foo\bar
otworking.txt
```

If I look at the string (user hits enter) coming into the controller (Spring based) I see `\n`.

Question is, how do I differentiate between someone typing `\n` and hitting the enter key?

Comment: When escaping, first escape every \ with \\.

Comment: I believe java also supports file's that are formatted such as `c:/foo/bar/notworking.txt` now as well, which would fix the error if you didn't want users using the \

Answer (score 1):

easiest solution:

```
String s = ...;
s = s.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
```

Then the opposite after you load it back in

Comment: That's what i'm currently using on the java side. I think [part of] my problem is that i'm posting json from jquery that has been "stringified" by jquery. jquery appears to be replacing the newline (0x0a) with a \n when the json string is built. Once java picks it up, both "newline" and \n look the same.

One issue I just noticed though with replace/replaceAll is that if a user types \\\\ (4 backslashes) the replaceAll (on the way back out to the ui) changes the 4 slashes to 2 slashes. s = s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"). I guess it would also take two slashes and change that to one...

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert raw text into a JSON column, you need to **encode** the text as JSON, meaning:

```
The following fails «badly»:
  "c:\foo\bar\notworking.txt"
```

encodes to (assuming non-ASCII needs encoding, which it does if the DB is not UTF-8):

```json
"The following fails \u00ABbadly\u00BB:\r\n  \"c:\\foo\\bar\\notworking.txt\""
```

Side note: As a Java String literal, that would be:

```
String json = "\"The following fails \\u00ABbadly\\u00BB:\\r\\n  \\\"c:\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\notworking.txt\\\"\"";
```

You will then of course use `PreparedStatement` or Spring, such that SQL escaping and SQL Injection issues are non-existent.